# Force relative debug symbol path (maven-native-plugin)

Tags: gcc, gdb, debug-symbols, native-maven-plugin

I am using the *native-maven-plugin* to compile a shared library on linux. I pass the compiler option `-g` to enable the debug symbol generation. Here is an excerpt from the POM:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory></workingDirectory>
                <compilerStartOptions>
                    <compilerStartOption>-g</compilerStartOption>
                </compilerStartOptions>
                <linkerStartOptions>
                    <linkerStartOption>-shared</linkerStartOption>
                    <linkerStartOption>-g</linkerStartOption>
                </linkerStartOptions>
                <sources>
                    ...
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The *native-maven-plugin* alsways uses absolute paths to the source files when invoking *gcc*. This results in absolute paths in the debug symbols, too.
The output of `nm -l libfoo.so` listing the debug symbols looks like:

```
0000797a T GetTickCount /home/myusername/projects/blabla/foo.c:3005
```

As you can see the source file path is absolute and includes my username and project structure. I don't want that. **How can I change the debug symbols to relative path names?**

Comment: You seem to be looking for this: [Using ORIGIN for a dynamic runtime library search path](http://itee.uq.edu.au/~daniel/using_origin/)

Comment: @devnull I read a bit and don't think this is related to my problem or I don't get it. I want to change the debug symbols, not finding/loading shared libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I found out there is a `-fdebug-prefix-map=oldPath=newPath` option in gcc which does exactly what I want. To compile the file `/home/myusername/projects/blabla/foo.c` from my question:

```
gcc -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/myusername/projects/blabla=theNewPathInDebug -o foo.o foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

Then the debug symbol paths will look like (`nm -l libfoo.so`):

```
0000797a T GetTickCount theNewPathInDebug/foo.c:3005
```

You can then use gdb path substitution to set the actual source file location for gdb.

To get everything working in maven, my pom looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <workingDirectory></workingDirectory>
            <compilerStartOptions>
                <compilerStartOption>-g</compilerStartOption>
                <compilerStartOption>-fdebug-prefix-map=${project.build.directory}/extracted-c=theNewPathInDebug</compilerStartOption>
            </compilerStartOptions>
            <linkerStartOptions>
                <linkerStartOption>-shared</linkerStartOption>
                <linkerStartOption>-g</linkerStartOption>
            </linkerStartOptions>
            <sources>
                <source>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/extracted-c</directory>
                    <fileNames>
                        <fileName>foo.c</fileName>
                    </fileNames>
                </source>
            </sources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Where *extracted-c* is the location where the *maven-dependency-plugin* extracts the C source/header files.

Comment: Very helpful, however this doesn't work quite right for me.  It looks like gcc is interpreting any relative path as the destination for `fdebug-prefix-map` relative to the current working dir (effectively the dir containing pom.xml).  So when running your example I get `/home/foo/project/blah/theNewPathInDebug` (as opposed to just `theNewPathInDebug`).  Does `fdebug-prefix-map` work with relative paths?  Googling turns up nothing.  I am using gcc 4.4.5.

Comment: The *newPath* argument is not a relative path in my case. It is just a (non existing) marker string. While debugging (possibly on a different machine) it can be substituted with the actual source path (gdb set substitute-path). Maybe it's treated differently when the marker string is also a valid relativ path and then substituted by gcc with the full path, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It appears to me that gcc is not treating the arguments to fdebug-prefix-map as paths at all. It just seems to be a kind of pattern substitution as I know it from Makefile rules. Maybe that helps.